# Width равная height

Tags: html, css

Натыкался на множество ответов на вопрос "Как сделать height = width". Но мне нужно наоборот: приравнять `width` к `height` при динамической `height`.

Есть растянутый на всю высоту элемента span

```
.span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Мне нужно сделать его ширину равную высоте. Как это можно сделать, с учетом того, что родитель `span`-а может изменить свою высоту? Желательно `css`, но видимо без `js` не получится

Comment: Думаю, без js/jquery тут не обойтись

Comment: @Cheg Сейчас сделаю на jquery, но все равно подожду еще ответов

Comment: @Mr Klonwar обновил ответ

Comment: @Cheg ширина должна зависит от высоты - 1 вариант так и работает, взависимости от высоты изменяется и ширина

Comment: @soledar10 а при чем тут `vh`, если ширина должна изменяться в зависимости от высоты блока, а не от высоты `viewport`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ширина равная высоте:

```css
div {
  position: relative;
}

textarea {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  opacity: .35;
  display: block;
  background: rgba(170, 171, 221, 0.61)
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  bottom: -100%;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <textarea>textarea для ресиза

нужно сделать ширину равную высоте
  </textarea>

  <span>
    123
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариант зависимости ширины от высоты

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.b {
    position: relative;
}

.b-inner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vh;
    background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="b">
    <div class="b-inner"></div>
</div>
```

Вариант зависимости высоты от ширины

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.aspect-ratio-1 {
  padding-bottom: 100%; /* (value height = value width) = 1 * 100% = 100%  */
  position: relative;
  background: #999;
}

.aspect-ratio-1-inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="aspect-ratio-1">
  <div class="aspect-ratio-1-inner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: И где тут решение? В вопросе же сказано, что нужно ширину прировнять к высоте, а не наоборот - как у вас.

Comment: Нет, не подходит( 
В моем коде из динамического height должен вычисляться wigth, если я все правильно понял, то тут наоборот. Да и мой `.span` должен быть `absolute`, так уж вышло

Comment: @Cheg равенство - коммутативная операция вроде как..

Comment: @Cheg обновил ответ

Comment: Vh не подойдет, мне нужно растянуть span не на высоту экрана, а на высоту родителя. VH растянет на высоту viewport-a, по простому, окна браузера